# Spring Data JPA & QueryDSL: filter on optional related entity

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

I have a slight problem with one query in QueryDSL.

I'm using Spring Data JPA with a QueryDslPredicateExecutor to search for entities that meet a certain filter, in this case actions that are in a particular status and have no dependencies or all dependencies satisfied.

Here is my simplified entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie_file_actions")
public class MovieFileAction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long                    id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private EActionStatus           status              = EActionStatus.QUEUED;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private MovieFileAction         parentAction        = null;

    // ...

}

@Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QMovieFileAction extends EntityPathBase<MovieFileAction> {

    public static final QMovieFileAction movieFileAction = new QMovieFileAction("movieFileAction");

    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);

    public final QMovieFile movieFile;

    public final QMovieFileAction parentAction;

    // ...

}
```

And this is my service and related Spring Data JPA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieFileActionRepository extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MovieFileAction>, PagingAndSortingRepository<MovieFileAction, Long> {}

@Service
@Transactional
public class MovieFileActionService {

    @Autowired
    MovieFileActionRepository mMovieFileActionRepository;

    public Page<MovieFileAction> findProcessable(Pageable page) {
        QMovieFileAction qMovieFileAction = QMovieFileAction.movieFileAction;

        BooleanExpression prdHasNoDependencies = qMovieFileAction.parentAction.isNull();
        BooleanExpression prdAreDependenciesSatisfied = qMovieFileAction.parentAction.status.eq( EActionStatus.SUCCESS );

        BooleanExpression predicate = qMovieFileAction.status.eq( EActionStatus.QUEUED )
            .and( prdHasNoDependencies.or( prdAreDependenciesSatisfied ) );

        return mMovieFileActionRepository.findAll( predicate, page );
    }

}
```

When I try to invoke the `findProcessable` method, I'd expect to get all `MovieFileAction`s which are either not dependent on anything or which have their dependency satisfied.

The HQL query that gets generated to check if any such action exist seems right to me:

```
select count(movieFileAction)
from MovieFileAction movieFileAction
where movieFileAction.status = ?1 
and (movieFileAction.parentAction is null or movieFileAction.parentAction.status = ?2)
```

The SQL that gets generated, however, is not what I expected:

```
select count(moviefilea0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
from movie_file_actions moviefilea0_ 
cross join movie_file_actions moviefilea1_ 
where moviefilea0_.parent_action=moviefilea1_.id 
and moviefilea0_.status=? and (moviefilea0_.parent_action is null or moviefilea1_.status=?)
```

Notice the cross join in the generated query, which is filtering out actions with no parents. Why is the cross join there? How do I tell JPA that parentAction is optional so as to generate a left join?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure but you can try named parameters or native query approach if you can write your query. Check this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.named-parameters